# Strong operator convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the operator $A \in B(L_2[0, 1])$, $A_n = A^n$, where $(A_nx)(t) = \int_{0}^{1}K_n(t, s)x(s)ds$, $K_n \in L_2([0, 1]^2)$ , I am trying to prove that this operator converges strongly to zero operator and does not converge in the norm, however i'm unable to prove this, can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: without further assumptions on $K$ this is not possible.

Comment: It may happen that $A_2=A^2=0.$ For example $K_1(t,s)=\sin (2\pi t)\cos(2\pi s).$ Hence $A_n=0$ for $n\ge 2$ and the convergence in norm holds trivially. On the other hand if for some $K_1(t,s)$ the norms $\|A_n\|$ do not converge to zero, they should be uniformly bounded. Otherwise  the strong convergence fails. Therefore additional assumptions are needed, as observed by @daw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K_1(t,s)=\overline{K}(s,t)$ then $A$ is a self-adjoint Hilbert-Schmidt operator and
$$\|A\|_{HS}=\left (\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1|K_1(x,y)|^2\,dx\,dy \right )^{1/2}$$
In particular $A$ is a compact self-adjoint operator. In this case norm convergence to $0$ coincides with the strong convergence to $0.$ Indeed, at least  one of the numbers $\lambda=\pm\|A\|$ is an eigenvalue of $A.$ Then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A_n=A^n.$ Hence $A_n$ tends to $0$ strongly iff $|\lambda|<1,$ i.e. $\|A_n\|=|\lambda|^n\to 0.$

Comment: I wonder, what if we set the operator $A_n$ in the definition above equal to $$\int_0^t K_n(t, s)x(s)ds$$

Comment: It does not change much as $$\int\limits_0^tK_1(t,s)x(s)\,ds=\int\limits_0^1\tilde{K}(t,s)x(s)\,ds$$ where $\tilde{K}(t,s)=K(t,s)$ for $0\le s\le t\le 1$ and $\tilde{K}(t,s)=0$ for $t<s\le 1.$